# when load a page into a div with jquery, javascript functions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to load a aspx page into a div which is on Default.aspx. I use this,

```
 $('div').load("Page.aspx");
```

It works correctly but javascript functions on Page.aspx doesn't work. Javascript codes are in plugins.js. I tried to include js file on Default.aspx and Page.aspx but it doesn't work. How can i make them work?

Comment: You will need to provide more information. Show us your HTML code for both `Default.aspx` and `Page.aspx`. A folder structure could also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i think the thing is that the Jquery function Load() gets the requested html content and inserts it in the dom, it doesnt load the javascript functions.

you could use

```
     document.write() function to get the requested javascript function
      and insert it in the html body preferrable a div at the top.
       for example:
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume this is because the content is being loaded into the page after jQuery has parsed the DOM.

Take a look at jQuery .live() (http://api.jquery.com/live/), which will allow you to attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now **and in the future**.

Comment: `live` is deprecated since 1.7 and has been removed since 1.9!